# How to mock file I/O in sinon?

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, sinon, ava

I have a function which  unzip a file form the directory. It's working fine

**index.js**

```
const unZip = async (zipFilePath, destDir) => {
  await util.promisify(fs.mkdir)(destDir);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath)
      .pipe(unzipper.Extract({ path: destDir }))
      .on("close", () => resolve(destDir))
      .on("error", (err) => {
        console.log("Error inside unzip", err);
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};
```

but for unit test i am using `sinon` and `ava`, where I am unable to pass the test case
here is the code

**index.test.js**

```
ava.beforeEach(() => {
  // mockFs({
  //   'fakeDir/fakeFile': mockFs.load('test/helpers/file/testFile.txt'),
  //   fakeFileContent: 'content here',
  // });
  sinon.stub(mockFs, 'createReadStream').returns({
    pipe: sinon.stub().returns({
      on: sinon.stub().returns({
        on: sinon.stub().returns(),
      }),
    }),
  });
});

ava.serial('unZip test', async (t) => {
  const unzip = proxyquire('../../../src/helpers/file/unZip', {
    fs: mockFs,
    util: {},
    unzipper: { Extract: () => Buffer.from([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]) },
  });

  const result = await unzip('fakeFileContent', 'fakeFileContent');

  t.is(result, true);
});
```

it's giving me the error like this

```
  unZip test

  Rejected promise returned by test. Reason:

  Error {
    code: 'EEXIST',
    errno: -17,
    path: 'fakeFileContent',
    syscall: 'mkdir',
    message: 'EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir \'fakeFileContent\'',
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

**index.test.js**

```
const mockFs = {
  createReadStream: function () {
    return this;
  },
  mkdir: function (p, cb) {
    cb(null, this);
  },
  pipe: function () {
    return this;
  },
  on: function (param, cb) {
    if (param === 'close') {
      return cb();
    }
    if (param === 'error') {
      return this;
    }
  },
};

ava.serial('unZip success', async (t) => {
  const unzip = proxyquire('../../../src/helpers/file/unZip', {
    fs: mockFs,
    util: {},
    unzipper: { Extract: () => Buffer.from([8, 6, 7, 5, 3, 0, 9]) },
  });
  const mockZipFilePath = '../file/testFile.txt';
  const destinationFilePath = '../file';

  const result = await unzip(mockZipFilePath, destinationFilePath);

  t.is(result, destinationFilePath);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `proxyquire` package, use `sinon.stub(obj, 'method')` to stub methods of object. You can stub `fs.mkdir`, `unzipper.Extract` and `fs.createReadStream` methods.

You use `util.promisify` to convert `fs.mkdir` into a promise form and call it, but underly is still the callback being called, so you need to use the `.callsFake()` method to mock implementation for `fs.mkdir`, and call the callback manually in the test case.

The below example uses `mocha` as testing framework, but `ava` should also be fine.

`index.js`:

```js
const fs = require('fs');
const util = require('util');
const unzipper = require('unzipper');

const unZip = async (zipFilePath, destDir) => {
  await util.promisify(fs.mkdir)(destDir);

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    fs.createReadStream(zipFilePath)
      .pipe(unzipper.Extract({ path: destDir }))
      .on('close', () => resolve(destDir))
      .on('error', (err) => {
        console.log('Error inside unzip', err);
        reject(err);
      });
  });
};

module.exports = unZip;
```

`index.test.js`:

```js
const unZip = require('./');
const fs = require('fs');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const unzipper = require('unzipper');

describe('69616649', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  it('should pass', async () => {
    sinon.stub(fs, 'mkdir').callsFake((path, callback) => {
      callback();
    });
    const rs = {
      pipe: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      on: sinon.stub().callsFake(function (event, callback) {
        if (event === 'close') {
          callback();
        }
      }),
    };
    sinon.stub(fs, 'createReadStream').returns(rs);
    sinon.stub(unzipper, 'Extract');
    const actual = await unZip('fakeFileContent', 'fakeFileContent');
    sinon.assert.match(actual, 'fakeFileContent');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(fs.mkdir, 'fakeFileContent', sinon.match.func);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(fs.createReadStream, 'fakeFileContent');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(unzipper.Extract, { path: 'fakeFileContent' });
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(rs.pipe);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(rs.on, 'close', sinon.match.func);
  });
});
```

test result:

```
  69616649
    ✓ should pass


  1 passing (7ms)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |   81.82 |      100 |      75 |   81.82 |                   
 index.js |   81.82 |      100 |      75 |   81.82 | 13-14             
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for the response but, your code doesn't work i have modify using ava, it's saying `Test finished without running any assertions` @slideshowp2

Comment: @NinjaDeveloper Did you change the `it` to `ava.serial`?

Comment: yes I have posted the mock in the answer @slideshowp2

Answer (score 0):

I am new to ava so may be it's wrong

```
proxyquire('../../../src/helpers/file/unZip')// actual function file

ava('69616649', () => {
  ava.afterEach(() => {
    sinon.restore();
  });
  ava.serial('should pass', async () => {
    sinon.stub(fs, 'mkdir').callsFake((path, callback) => {
      callback();
    });
    const rs = {
      pipe: sinon.stub().returnsThis(),
      on: sinon.stub().callsFake(function (event, callback) {
        if (event === 'close') {
          callback();
        }
      }),
    };
    sinon.stub(fs, 'createReadStream').returns(rs);
    sinon.stub(unzipper, 'Extract');
    const actual = await unZip('fakeFileContent', 'fakeFileContent');
    sinon.assert.match(actual, 'fakeFileContent');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(
      fs.mkdir,
      'fakeFileContent',
      sinon.match.func
    );
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(fs.createReadStream, 'fakeFileContent');
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(unzipper.Extract, {
      path: 'fakeFileContent',
    });
    sinon.assert.calledOnce(rs.pipe);
    sinon.assert.calledWithExactly(rs.on, 'close', sinon.match.func);
  });
});
```